# pronunciation of "excuser"

Tags: prononciation

The [Word Reference dictionary](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/excuser) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/excuser) say that the correct pronunciation of the verb "excuser" is [ɛkskyze] with a open E at the beginning (as in hiEr), but I hear a closed E (/e/) in the beginning of the word in the available audios in the two webpages. Am I listening right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Excuser* can have several pronunciations:

- The careful/formal one is /**ɛkskyze**/.
- Due to the difficulty of the sequence /ksk/, a more common pronunciation is dropping the first /k/ leading to /**ɛskyze**/.
- The first vowel might also be partially or totally dropped in relaxed French, especially in conjugated forms like *excusez-moi*, leading to /**skuze** mwa/.

Using /e/ like in the first linked page (/**ekskyze**/) doesn't prevent understanding and would likely be unnoticed by most native speakers.

Answer (score 3):

I also hear an [e] on the French recording on the Word Reference dictionary. To my hears, it sounds quite artificial and not representative of the common pronunciation with [ɛ]. Note that on the Canadian audio, you can clearly hear an [ɛ].

On the Wiktionary entry, on the contrary, I hear a clear [ɛ]. It is a pity that the audio is for *s'excuser* and not *excuser* alone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The Wiktionary webpage uses [ɛ] indeed, I think that yesterday my ear somehow got influenced by listening to the WR French audio several times.

Comment: As jiliagre said, in any case, the pronunciation with [e] would anyway be barely noticed and there is no chance of a confusion with another word.